# Crear base de datos PostgreSQL desde un .bat

Tags: postgresql, .bat

no se si he formulado correctamente la pregunta pero explicare que es lo que necesito exactamente, para que sea mas entendible vamos desde el principio.

Tengo un proyecto hecho en NetBeans, es un proyecto finalizado el cual ejecuto en otras maquinas, originalmente lo que hacia era llevar el ejecutable, luego instalar java después PostgreSQL para posteriormente restaurar la base de datos y así el programa funcione correctamente en otros equipos, para evitar todo este proceso me vi en la necesidad de crear un .exe de mi programa y empaquetarlo junto con java, PostgreSQL y un .reg que sea crea en el editor de registro de Windows para poder ejecutar la base de datos (Todos estos programas a excepción del .exe del proyecto los ejecuto de forma silenciosa o desatendida desde un .bat junto con sus configuraciones) ahora lo que necesito es crear la base de datos de mi proyecto en el ya instalada postgres desde un .bat, en un principio la base de datos debe estar vacía ya que luego ejecutare otro scrip para poder hacer un restore (Pero ese ya es otro tema) por el momento solo me interesa crearla aunque sea vacía, en la linea de comandos SQL shell (psql) esto lo puedo hacer facilmente sin ningun problema sin embargo en un .bat no tengo la misma suerte en primer lugar porque no se cual ese es el scrip correcto y en segundo lugar porque debo ingresar una contraseña que debo onmitir.

[image: Esto funciona muy bien si voy a postgres la base de datos "pruebaLineaDecomandos" esta creada sin problemas]

ahora en el .bat logicamente necesito que todos los campos señalados se puedan hacer en una sola linea poner el host el puerto el usuario y la contraseña y posteriormente crear la base de datos.
He utilizado muchisimos comandos pero nada funciona entre ellos:

```
CREATE DATABASE "Prueba13"
WITH OWNER = postgres
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
TABLESPACE = pg_default
LC_COLLATE = 'Spanish_Mexico.1252'
LC_CTYPE = 'Spanish_Mexico.1252'
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

Otro

psql -U postgres postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE MydatAbseName WITH OWNER Myadmin
EMPLATE template ENCODING 'SQL_ASCII' TABLESPACE  pg_default LC_COLLATE  'C'
LC_CTYPE  C' CONNECTION LIMIT  -1"

y otro...

psql -d postgres12 -U postgres -p 5432 -c 'create database NoseQueHacer'
```

Y asi puedo seguir poniendo todos los comandos que he probado pero nada me funciona, espero me puedan orientar de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola. Bonita pregunta. Sin embargo, cada vez que digas "no me funciona", procura siempre poner el error específico que obtienes al probar tu propio código. Recuerda además que puedes editar tu pregunta todas las veces que haga falta y añadir la info relevante que pueda servirle a los que intentan responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceder a una base de datos (segura) siempre será difícil sin una contraseña de acceso. El paso de saltarte la contraseña no sería lo mejor. Entiendo que debes crear una base de datos por llamarle así "portable" sin necesidad de teclear una contraseña, pero no se si sea la mejor manera.

Podrías revisar este post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901209/create-database-and-tables-from-batch-file
Ahí hay varias alternativas que podrían orientarte.

En este otro link hay scripts que te podrían ayudar.
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/using-batch-scripts-and-sqlcmd-to-write-out-a-databases-data/

Echa un vistazo a https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208231/how-to-create-a-new-database-in-postgresql-10-in-windows-from-batch-file
Hay un script que parece adaptarse a lo que pretendes hacer.

Si es de plano quieres omitir la contraseña de acceso, mira este post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100

Parece que debes colocar esto para esquivar la solicitud de contraseña:

```
-w
--no-password
```

Perdón por poner muchos links, pero creo que podrán servirte de ayuda.

Comment: Estos comandos `-w
--no-password` ya los probe sin embargo no me funcionas pero realmente agradezco que te tomes el tiempo en facilitarme estos links

Comment: Comentarte que he marcado tu respuesta como util, uno de los links que em has compartido solucionó perfectamente mi problema!!!

Comment: De nada, espero haberte ahorrado tiempo de buscar.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a uno de los links que me compartió la respuesta marcada he logrado solucionar mi problema el resultado seria el siguiente espero que le sirva a alguien en el futuro!

Una vez tengo mi archivo crearBaseDeDatos.bat utilizo el siguiente comando:

```
@SET PGPASSWORD=12345
"C:\postgresql\bin\createdb.exe" -U postgres MiBaseDeDatos
```

> **@SET PGPASSWORD=12345** Esta seria la contraseña que utilizaste al momento de instalar
> PostgreSQL y fácilmente con el comando `SET PGPASSWORD` ya no
> tendríamos ningún problema al momento de que nos pide la
> contraseña por el echo que ya la hemos asignado en nuestro bat.
>
> **"C:\postgresql\bin\createdb.exe"** -U postgres MiBaseDeDatos //Buscamos la ruta de
> instalación donde se creo
> la carpeta postgres con el archivo **createdb.exe** creamos la base de datos, **-U postgres** es el nombre de usuario que nos asigna `PostgreSQL` por defecto y por ultimo escribimos el nombre de nuestra base de datos **MiBaseDeDatos**.